# Probability that a bridge hand has at most $k$ points

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to calculate the exact probability that a random bridge hand has at most
 $k$ points , where $0\le k \le 37$ (more than $37$ points is not possible)

For non-bridge-players : A bridge hand consists of $13$ cards out of a normal
 $52$-card-deck. Every Jack counts $1$ point , every queen $2$, every king $3$ and every ace $4$ points.

I managed to calculate the probabilities with PARI, but I am looking for a 
 more efficient method which avoids to add many multinomial coefficients.

- Is there an easy way to calculate the desired probability (denoted $P(k)$) ?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining there is a really slick method as there are (for most $k$) plenty of  ways in which you can obtain $k$ points and these ways are  not very structured. But perhaps somebody will surprise me.

Comment: p(k) = 1 if k = 37 and, if i understood correctly, p(k) > p(k-1) for every k?

Comment: Yes, $P(37)=1$ holds. And $P(k)$ strictly increases because $P(0)$ to $P(37)$ are all positive.

Comment: Do your PARI results agree with http://www.durangobill.com/BrPtCntStats.html ?

Comment: $P(0)$ would be the chance of getting only useless cards, of which there are 36 out of 52, so it'd be $P(0) = \frac{36}{52}*\frac{35}{51}...*\frac{23}{39}$

Comment: @barry It seems to coincide. Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: PARI code:
P(k)=(1/binomial(52,13))*Vec((1/(1-x))*polcoeff((1+a_)^36*(1+a_*x)^4*(1+a_*x^2)^4*(‌​1+a_*x^3)^4*(1+a_*x^4)^4,13,a_)+O(x^38))[k+1]